# A theorem by R.L. Moore

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

The following result is due to R.L. Moore.

Let $K\subseteq\mathbb C$ be compact. Suppose that
$K$ is connected,
and that  $\mathbb C\setminus K$ is connected.
Then $\partial K$ is connected.

Does anyone know the  original source? Thank you.